# Docker-compose mount postgress database for tests

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to put together a compose file for my development environment, but I'm having problems finding some convinient way to setup a database filled with test data. I tried mounting directory from my project as a data folder for postgres container, but it mounts as root and postgres throws:

```
data directory “/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata” has wrong ownership
```

Named volume works, but it would be problematic to use it with a git repo.

I could also just copy data directly into a docker image, but then I'd have to rebuild it whenever data changes.

Is there any other way around this?

Comment: Change the owner/group of the file (`chown`)?

Comment: why is named volume problematic to be used with a git repo?

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski I created Dockerfile for postgres and added `RUN mkdir -p "$PGDATA" && chown postgres "$PGDATA"` (PGDATA set to `/var/lib/postgresql/data`) I still get `FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership` I guess ownership changes when compose mounts volume.

Comment: You need to do the chown on the directory you mount - not the directory within the container (dockerfile).

The mounted directory overrides whatever is in the container.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski you mean changing owner of directory on host?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to determine the userid of the postgresql user, this can be done with `id -u postgres` (within the container).

Replace `1234` with the id you get from the above.

Then on the volume that you mount, from the host you need to do `chown -R 1234:1234 path/to/volume/that/you/are/mounting`.

Comment: Possibly as a work around you could docker exec into the container and run the chown from within the container.

Comment: Not possible since container is stopped after fatal is rised. I could theorethically write bash script to switch ownership and use it as entrypoint, but thats starting to get messy.